# How to setup debugging Qt apps on OSX Mountain Lion with Qt-Creator?

Tags: xcode, qt, qt4, qt-creator, qt5

Ok guys, I've got both Qt-Creator and Xcode and the usual suite of OSX development tools.  I've followed every set of instructions I can find on the web, with a bunch of variations, and cannot get breakpoints to work either inside Xcode or in Qt-Creator.

What's the secret recipe?  I'm running OSX 10.8.4, Qt Creator 2.7.0 (Qt 5.0.2), Xcode 4.6.3 (4H1503) and I'm trying to debug a complex open source Qt-based app.

I've tried configuring the project inside Qt Creator to use either Qt5 or Qt4 with the same results.  As far as I can tell Qt Creator is building my app with debugging turned on. However, when I run in debug mode, my breakpoints are not hit.

I've tried generating an Xcode project file with `qmake -spec macx-xcode` but this results in a project file that the current version of Xcode cannot read.

Really appreciate any help getting past this roadblock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can you tell that Qt Creator is compiling in debug mode? Have you got -g flag in the Makefile?

If you create the project in Qt Creator, it should be enough to choose the Debug option as in this image:

[image]

Comment: Yep, I have selected the Debug option as you illustrated. Are there other options I need to check?   Is there a way I can verify that a debug build is being built? Thanks!

Comment: In `Projects mode` verify the settings for debug configuration, particularly `Build steps / Effective quake call`. Than realunch `qmake` in `Build` menu.

Comment: The effective qmake call is: qmake qgroundcontrol.pro -r -spec macx-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=x86_64 CONFIG+=declarative_debug   .... I see CONFIG+=debug in there, which I've read turns on debug build.  What else could I be doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: It seems ok. Verify the `Build directory`; go in it, verify that the Makefile has the `-g` option for the compiler. If not, you may add it and rebuild from the terminal with `make clean` and `make build`, then  you can run your application by Qt Creator. (Are you sure that the breakpoint is in a good position?)

Comment: After some reconfiguration I am able to hit SOME breakpoints; however, I am not able to hit a breakpoint where I really want to.  I'll create a followup question --thanks.